# state undefined: while sending post request from react app

Tags: reactjs, components, react-state

I am new in react and trying to send post request to an api and getting state undefined while sending post request from react app, i this occurs  because state stores data as an object. Dont know how to solve this. i would really appreciate some help.

[image: click here to see image]

compmonent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Register extends Component {

  register () {
    // alert('register')
    console.warn('state', this.state)
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/accounts/registration/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem('register', JSON.stringify(resp.data.token))
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='email'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ email: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>First name</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='first name'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ first_name: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Last name</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='last name'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ last_name: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type='password' placeholder='password'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ password1: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Confirm password</label>
          <input
            type='password' placeholder='confirm password'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ password2: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <button onClick={() => this.register()}>Register</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Register
```

thanks

Comment: where is your state object?

Comment: that is not state object. that is setting state. please check my answer

Comment: onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ email: e.target.value }) }}  storing data in state

Comment: but when i am printing it on console it shows as an object plz see the image above

Comment: @RedBaron it will not be a problem if register function is called after change of input

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes but I can't see where his initial state object is?

Comment: so how do you `setState` when that does not exist?

Comment: @RedBaron A sample working demo for you https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snow-xvql3?file=/src/App.js. If you tried to use state before it is defined you will get an error, but not after you call setState and set it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri interesting! I still think it's good to explicitly declare state but that is interesting to know

Comment: @RedBaron Yeah, so not declaring state is not a cause of OP issue, but yes it is a good practise to declare state

Comment: agree. I have removed my answer below now as it doesn't fix the OP problem

Comment: issue resolved . Problem was with Accept:application/json.. now its working . Thanks for your help @RedBaron

Comment: thanks @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok,

I've created a runnable code snippet from your code, only time `state` is `null` and not `undefined`, is when you don't fill-up the form and submit,

for that you can put a condition before making fetch request.

---

You can run the below code snippet and check :

```js
class App extends React.Component {

register () {
    // alert('register')
    console.warn('state', this.state)
    if (this.state) { // <------ HERE
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          // Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
      }).then((result) => {
        result.json().then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp.data.token)
          localStorage.setItem('register', JSON.stringify(resp.data.token))
        })
      })    
    }

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='email'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ email: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>First name</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='first name'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ first_name: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Last name</label>
          <input
            type='text' placeholder='last name'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ last_name: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type='password' placeholder='password'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ password1: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <label>Confirm password</label>
          <input
            type='password' placeholder='confirm password'
            onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ password2: e.target.value }) }}
          /><br /><br />

          <button onClick={() => this.register()}>Register</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: issue resolved . Problem was with Accept:application/json.. Thanks for your help