# Error when sending POST request from React app to Rocket backend returns failure

Tags: reactjs, rust, preflight, rust-rocket

I'm writing a simple web with Rocket as backend and React as frontend.

The code snippet looks like this for login page

```rust
#[post("/login", data = "<data>")]
pub fn login(
    conn: DbConn,
    mut cookies: Cookies<'_>,
    data: Form<LoginForm>,
) -> Result<JsonValue, NotFound<String>> {
    let valid_account = match Account::find_by_email(&*conn, data.email.as_str()) {
        Ok(account) => {
            if account.password == data.password {
                account
            } else {
                return Err(NotFound("Incorrect email or password!".to_string()));
            }
        }
        Err(_) => return Err(NotFound("Incorrect email or password!".to_string())),
    };

    cookies.add_private(
        Cookie::build(AUTH_COOKIE, valid_account.id.to_string())
            .same_site(rocket::http::SameSite::Strict)
            .finish(),
    );
    Ok(json!({
        "email": valid_account.email,
        "name": valid_account.name,
    }))
}
```

Code for `main.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![
                account::login::login,
            ],
        )
        .register(catchers![errors::unauthorized])
        .attach(rocket_cors::CorsOptions::default().to_cors().unwrap())
        .manage(establish_connection())
        .launch();
}
```

and code for React when trying to send the post request

```js
export const postForm = async (
  pathUrl: string,
  postInfo: { [name: string]: any }
) => {
  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      baseUrl + pathUrl,
      querystringify.stringify(postInfo),
      axiosConfig
    );
    return response.data as CurrentUser;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err.response);
  }
};
```

The code works fine it I enter the correct email and password.
However, it cannot capture the error message if I enter the wrong credentials.
Rocket log are the same between successful login and failure login which are

```
OPTIONS /login:
    => Error: No matching routes for OPTIONS /login.
    => Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher.
    => CORS Fairing: Turned missing route OPTIONS /login into an OPTIONS pre-flight request
    => Response succeeded.
POST /login application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
    => Matched: POST /login (login)
    => Outcome: Success
    => Response succeeded.
```

and the error log in browser I captured was `Error: "Request failed with status code 404"` which was not the expected error message hard coded inside post function.

I believe it has something to do with `Option` or `preflight` processed inside Rocket which maybe in the purpose of security. But how can I suppress the system error and let my code to take over?

I have read previous SO post like [state undefined: while sending post request from react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278812/state-undefined-while-sending-post-request-from-react-app) and GitHub issues like https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/25. And still cannot find answer for my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I made several mistakes here due to unfamiliar with Rocket and React.
List here in case someone made the similar mistakes.

The `404` status code is from the first code snippets `Result<JsonValue, NotFound<String>>`. So if we write the return type as `Result<JsonValue, Unauthorized<String>>`, it would return `401` as unauthorized user.

Second, `axios` only receives json type and cannot parse string (correct me if I'm wrong). So we need to change the return type in server to `Result<JsonValue, Unauthorized<JsonValue>>`.